# Change Starcraft 2 level editor language

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to change the level editor's language? It's in some asian language somehow...

[image]

Comment: Does someone know? ._.

Comment: Well, I can tell you the language is Traditional Chinese, and what you see there is a short description of the map editor, a disclaimer that Blizzard does not provide support for the map editor (so their customer service won't help you if you contact them) and that by using it you agree to the EULA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes There is a way to change GUI language to english

Click to File then press "p" you ll see a preferances panel opening up

Change Locale to English
and there you go,

Also take a look at this link
https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/13681698107